# JS creating object in object with constructor

Tags: javascript, oop, properties

i have problem with assigning property to a object created with constructor INSIDE other function

```
   var something = {
    property1: 'sth',
    object: new Object()
    }
```

and it works it creates object inside a object, but everytime i try to assign property to object inside object like

```
var something = {
    property1: 'sth',
    object: new Object(),
    object.property: 'anything'
    }
```

it shows error, Uncaught syntaxError: unexpected token . , albo tried with object['property'] but shows "unexpected token [", so how do i assign it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in two steps:

```
var something = {
  property1: 'sth',
  object: new Object(),
};

something.object.property = 'anything';
```

Or use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to merge properties into the created object:

```
var something = {
  property1: 'sth',
  object: Object.assign(new Object(), {
    property: 'anything',
  }),
};
```

---

Of course if *you* are the one creating the object (as opposed to some third party function creating the object), there is no need to use `new Object`. Just use an object literal as well.

Comment: why not `object: { property: 'anything' }`?

Comment: I assumed that `new Object` is a placeholder for something like `someThirdPartyFunctionCreatingAnObject()`.